# login error mysql command line 5.6

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql 5.6 on windows 7(32 bit).
When I open command line client 5.6 it asks me for password i put password (mysql) and press enter, it gives connection id number, meaning connection was successful. I created a database by the name bank

create database bank;
it was created.

I created the lrngsql database user with full privileges on the bank database using following command

Grant all privileges on bank.* to 'lrngsql'@'localhost' identified by 'xyz';
It was successful too. Now here my query begins, how do i login to this user (lrngsql). the command i m typing in prompt

mysql>use bank;
-- it says Database changed.

then i type following command to login to lrngsql

mysql -u lrngsql -p xyz;
but it gives me error please help me what should i exactly type in order to get in to lrngsql user on bank database. thank you[image]

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If my answer helped you, will you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: no it did not. i assumed that i will not be able to login to mysql using command line tool using other users. i think i can login to only root using command line tool.

Comment: also i am trying to find out how do i mark it accepted

Comment: First, connect to mysql. Then select a DB. Then do some queries. Then `quit`. Then connect again to mysql with another user. And select a DB. And do queries. etc...etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already logged in, you need to log out in order to log in again with another user. You can cancel your connection with the `quit` command.

Just type `quit` in the prompt and the connection will be closed.